# Blazor - How can I call a component outside of other components/pages? For example in a simple class

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

My goal is to make something like the Winforms-MessageBox, just in Blazor.

For simplicity, this here is the component I want to call:

CustomDialog.razor

```
<dialog open="@DialogOpen">@ShownText</dialog>

@code {

    private bool dialogOpen;
    [Parameter]
    public bool DialogOpen { get { return dialogOpen; } set { dialogOpen = value; } }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> DialogOpenChanged { get; set; }

    string shownText = "Test";
    [Parameter]
    public string ShownText { get { return shownText; } set { shownText = value; } }
}
```

And then I would like to call it like that in a new separate class file:

```
public class User
{
   public User(string name)
   {
       Name = name;
       MessageBox.Show($"New user {Name} created.");
   }

   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I found out, you can't just make an instance of a component and call it like the Winforms-MessageBox, so I tried to anchor the dialog-component into the _Host.cshtml file, via:

`<component type="typeof(CustomDialog)" render-mode="Server" param-ShownText=@("Test") param-DialogOpen="true"/>`

It is shown in the application, but I don't know how I could change the values for the open parameter and the text parameter from the outside of the _Host.cshtml.

My idea was to have the component laying there to be "invisible" until needed and then just change the shownText, when it should appear.

How can I make this going to work?

Comment: There are allrady components doing this like [Blazored.Modal][ https://github.com/Blazored/Modal] or [mudblazor MessageBox][https://mudblazor.com/components/messagebox#message-box] you need to work with Cascading Values if you like to it by your own.

Comment: You can't control the Ui directly from a data class.  Search `Blazor Modal Dialogs` and see how they are used.  It looks like what you could use is Toasts.  Again search `Blazor Toasts`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a component directly from a service or data class, and you shouldn't attempt to pass a component to a data class.

You can use a service as an intermediary to communicate with a modal dialog.  This uses events that the modal dialog component registers for and reacts to.  Take a look at the various Blazor Modal Dialogs by searching `Blazor Modal Dialog`.

The other option for this type of notification is to use Toasts.  Again search for `Blazor Toasts`.